# xna zoom using mouse scroll wheel

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

How do i zoom using the mouse scroll wheel, i got try this

```cs
        if (currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue < originalMouseState.ScrollWheelValue)
        {
            cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
            UpdateViewMatrix();
            currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue.Equals(0);
        }
        if (currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue > originalMouseState.ScrollWheelValue)
        {
            cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            UpdateViewMatrix();
            currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue.Equals(0);
        }
```

But i keep zooming in even if i scroll once and i am kinda new to XNA. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ScrollWheelValue` gets the cumulative mouse scroll wheel value since the game was started, so every time you get it you need to copy that value in a variable, in order to compare it the next cycle.

Moreover, you can't set `ScrollWheelValue`, and this line is wrong:

```
currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue.Equals(0);
```

I think your idea was to set its value as 0, but that instruction compares its value with 0 and gives you a boolean.

**EDIT:**
You should do something like this:

Declare a global variable

`private int previousScrollValue;`

And set it in the `Initialize` method as:

`previousScrollValue = originalMouseState.ScrollWheelValue;`

Then edit your code as this:

```cs
if (currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue < previousScrollValue)
{
    cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
    UpdateViewMatrix();
}
else if (currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue > previousScrollValue)
{
    cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    UpdateViewMatrix();
}
previousScrollValue = currentMouseState.ScrollWheelValue;
```

It should work.

Comment: so how do i zoom like normal RTS style?

Comment: oh its ok..i manage to figure it out, i got 2 mousestate so that why its keep zooming and didn't stop. Thanks for helping!